# Content with characters ', " or & may need to be escaped with three brackets

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using SendGrid to send emails and I keep getting this warning which causes the email not to be sent.

```
Content with characters ', " or & may need to be escaped with three brackets
```

In my email I have a BUTTON with a BUTTON URL that looks like this {{link}}.  The link  has & which is causing this warning.  I tried to use {{{link}}} but I am still getting the same warning and the email is not being sent.

I looked at documentation, and it says that I can hide the warning.  I tried that but now I don't get the warning and the email is still not sent.  I need the email to be sent.  What should I do??

Here is my message:

```
    const message = {
      to: email,
      from: 'noreply@oolfa.com',
      templateId: sgMailVerifyEmailTemplateId,
      dynamic_template_data: { link },
      hideWarnings: true,
    };
    await sgMail.send(message);
```

Thanks

Comment: That is only a warning that shouldn't stop emails being sent. Do you receive an error when you try to send it? Or are there logs in your [SendGrid console](https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity) that show what happened to the email?

Comment: I get the warning and the email is never sent.  I checked the activity feed and there is nothing there.  When I hide the warning, the warning goes away and the email still does not go through.  If I replace the link that is causing the warning with another basic link that does not have "&", then everything goes well.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm not sure. It might be best to contact [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) and let them know what you've done so far.

Comment: any resolution to this @AimnBlbol?